# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'D' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been staring at this query for 20 minutes and I can't see why I am getting the error in the title. Can you understand why this is happening? Thanks!

```
 SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME  = '2016-06-05 00:00:00.000';
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2016-08-06 23:59:59.000';
select count(tptC.MovConID)  as [Count of Collections], sum(cgtC.[Chargeable weight]) as [Total Col Chg Wt], sum(tptrevenueC.amount)  as [Rev Col],
count(tptD.MovConID) as [Count of Deliveries], sum(cgtD.[Chargeable weight]) as [Total Del Chg Wt], sum(tptrevenueD.amount) as [Rev Del]
from tptVehicle tptv
inner join tptHeader tpth on tpth.VehicleID = tptv.VehicleID
left join tptDetails tptC on tptC.RunID = tpth.RunID and tptC.RunType = 'C'
left join tptDetails tptD on tptD.RunID = tpth.RunID and tptD.RunID = 'D'
left join tptVehicleRevenueDaily tptrevenueC on tptrevenueC.Reference = tptC.MovConID
left join tptVehicleRevenueDaily tptrevenueD on tptrevenueD.Reference = tptD.MovConID
left join cgtConsignment cgtC on cgtC.[Consignment Reference] = tptrevenueC.Reference
left join cgtConsignment cgtD on cgtD.[Consignment Reference] = tptrevenueD.Reference
where tpth.JourneyDate >= @StartDate and tpth.JourneyDate <= @EndDate and tpth.RunReference like 'belf%'
```

Comment: What's the datatype of `tptD.RunID`?

Comment: @SchmitzIT - your question made me realise my mistake and I have corrected it now so it's working fine! thank you :)

Comment: No worries, I'm happy to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because tpt.RunID is an `int`, and you're trying to compare it to `'D'` in one of your `left join`s.

Try changing this:

```
left join tptDetails tptD on tptD.RunID = tpth.RunID and tptD.RunID = 'D'
```

to this:

```
left join tptDetails tptD on tptD.RunID = tpth.RunID and tptD.RunType = 'D'
```